# A way to push buffered events in even intervals

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

What I'm trying to achieve is to buffer incoming events from some IObservable ( they come in bursts) and release them further, but one by one, in even intervals.
Like this:

```
-oo-ooo-oo------------------oooo-oo-o-------------->

-o--o--o--o--o--o--o--------o--o--o--o--o--o--o---->
```

Since I'm quite new to **Rx**, I'm not sure if there already is a Subject or an operator that does just this. Maybe It can be done by composition?

**update:**

Thanks to
[Richard Szalay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3603/richard-szalay) for pointing out the **Drain** operator, I found another [example by James Miles](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/749771d5-544b-4619-adff-6e79b2906152) of Drain operator usage. Here's how I managed to get it to work in a WPF app:

```
    .Drain(x => {
        Process(x);
        return Observable.Return(new Unit())
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Scheduler.Dispatcher );
    }).Subscribe();
```

I had some fun, because omitting the scheduler parameter causes the app to crash in debug mode without any exception showing up ( I need to learn how to deal with exceptions in Rx).
The Process method modifies the UI state directly, but I guess it's quite simple to make an IObservable out of it (using a ISubject?).

**update:**

In the meantime I've been experimenting with ISubject, the class below does what I wanted - it lets out buffered Ts in a timely manner:

```
public class StepSubject<T> : ISubject<T>
{
    IObserver<T> subscriber;
    Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();
    MutableDisposable cancel = new MutableDisposable();
    TimeSpan interval;
    IScheduler scheduler;
    bool idle = true;

    public StepSubject(TimeSpan interval, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        this.interval = interval;
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    void Step()
    {
        T next;
        lock (queue)
        {
            idle = queue.Count == 0;
            if (!idle)
                next = queue.Dequeue();
        }

        if (!idle)
        {
            cancel.Disposable = scheduler.Schedule(Step, interval);
            subscriber.OnNext(next);
        }
    }

    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
        lock (queue)
            queue.Enqueue(value);

        if (idle)
            cancel.Disposable = scheduler.Schedule(Step);
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        subscriber = observer;
        return cancel;
    }
}
```

This naive implementation is stripped from OnCompleted and OnError for clarity, also only single subscription allowed.

Comment: Your subject is not threadsafe. You're checking if your queue is empty within a lock, but then dequeue'ing outside the lock.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's actually tricker than it sounds.

Using `Delay` doesn't work because the values will still happen in bulk, only slightly delayed.

Using `Interval` with either `CombineLatest` or `Zip` doesn't work, since the former will cause source values to be skipped and the latter will buffer interval values.

I think the new `Drain` operator ([added in 1.0.2787.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rxteam/release-notes)), combined with `Delay` should do the trick:

```
source.Drain(x => Observable.Empty<int>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).StartWith(x));
```

The `Drain` operator works like `SelectMany`, but waits until the previous output completes before calling the selector with the next value. <strike>It's still not *exactly* what you are after (the first value in a block will also be delayed), but it's close:</strike> The usage above matches your marble diagram now.

**Edit:** Apparently the `Drain` in the framework doesn't work like `SelectMany`. I'll ask for some advice in the official forums. In the meantime, here's an implementation of Drain that does what you're after:

**Edit 09/11:** Fixed errors in implementation and updated usage to match your requested marble diagram.

```
public static class ObservableDrainExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<TOut> Drain<TSource, TOut>(this IObservable<TSource> source, 
        Func<TSource, IObservable<TOut>> selector)
    {
        return Observable.Defer(() =>
        {
            BehaviorSubject<Unit> queue = new BehaviorSubject<Unit>(new Unit());

            return source
                .Zip(queue, (v, q) => v)
                .SelectMany(v => selector(v)
                    .Do(_ => { }, () => queue.OnNext(new Unit()))
                );
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Drain is close, but the main problem is that it doesn't return a IObservable<T>, so I can't use it in a query or chain it with other operators. It expects the Func parameter to return a IObservable<Unit>, that prevents your sample from compiling.

Comment: Unfortunately I have problems with compiling that example too :(

Comment: Thanks for the update! I tried to use the function with .Drain(s => Observable.Return(s).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Scheduler.Dispatcher))   and it works, apart from delaying the first notification.

Comment: Not a problem. If you use the updated usage (`Observable.Empty...`) then it should work without the delay on the first item (matching your original marble diagram)

Comment: Is the canonical `Drain` operator what we should use as of now or the extension method you've described here?

Comment: @Asad It's been a while, but the `Drain` in the framework definitely acted differently. I don't remember the specifics, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness here is an alterantive (more compact) version of the Drain() method suggested by Richard:

```
public static IObservable<T2> SelectManySequential<T1, T2>(
    this IObservable<T1> source, 
    Func<T1, IObservable<T2>> selector
)
{
    return source
        .Select(x => Observable.Defer<T2>(() => selector(x)))
        .Concat();
}
```

See the thread [Drain + SelectMany = ?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/ae2609a9-1259-45f7-8aa3-ceb68d681b0b) in the Rx forum.

**Update:**
I realized that the Concat() overload that I used was one of my personal Rx extensions that are (not yet) part of the framework. I am sorry for this mistake .. Of course this makes my solution less elegant than I thought.

Nevertheless for completeness I post here my Conact() extension method overload:

```
public static IObservable<T> Concat<T>(this IObservable<IObservable<T>> source)
{
    return Observable.CreateWithDisposable<T>(o =>
    {
        var lockCookie = new Object();
        bool completed = false;
        bool subscribed = false;
        var waiting = new Queue<IObservable<T>>();
        var pendingSubscription = new MutableDisposable();

        Action<Exception> errorHandler = e =>
        {
            o.OnError(e);
            pendingSubscription.Dispose();
        };

        Func<IObservable<T>, IDisposable> subscribe = null;
        subscribe = (ob) =>
        {
            subscribed = true;
            return ob.Subscribe(
                o.OnNext,
                errorHandler,
                () =>
                {
                    lock (lockCookie)
                    {
                        if (waiting.Count > 0)
                            pendingSubscription.Disposable = subscribe(waiting.Dequeue());
                        else if (completed)
                            o.OnCompleted();
                        else
                            subscribed = false;
                    }
                }
            );
        };

        return new CompositeDisposable(pendingSubscription,
            source.Subscribe(
                n =>
                {
                    lock (lockCookie)
                    {
                        if (!subscribed)
                            pendingSubscription.Disposable = subscribe(n);
                        else
                            waiting.Enqueue(n);
                    }

                },
                errorHandler
                , () =>
                {
                    lock (lockCookie)
                    {
                        completed = true;
                        if (!subscribed)
                            o.OnCompleted();
                    }
                }
            )
        );
    });
}
```

And now beating myself with my own weapons: 
The same Concat() method could be written much more elegant in Richard Szalay's brilliant way:

```
public static IObservable<T> Concat<T>(this IObservable<IObservable<T>> source)
{
    return Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        BehaviorSubject<Unit> queue = new BehaviorSubject<Unit>(new Unit());
        return source
            .Zip(queue, (v, q) => v)
            .SelectMany(v => 
                v.Do(_ => { }, () => queue.OnNext(new Unit()))
            );
    });
}
```

So credit belongs to Richard. :-)

Comment: Indeed, elegant and brilliant! Grasping that "short-circuit" way took me some time, but the satisfaction when I finally did understand it is priceless :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did this, just using an explicit queue (ReactiveCollection is just a fancy version of WPF's ObservableCollection - ReactiveCollection.ItemsAdded OnNext's for each item added, as you can imagine):

https://github.com/xpaulbettsx/ReactiveXaml/blob/master/ReactiveXaml/ReactiveCollection.cs#L309

```
public static ReactiveCollection<T> CreateCollection<T>(this IObservable<T> FromObservable, TimeSpan? WithDelay = null)
{
    var ret = new ReactiveCollection<T>();
    if (WithDelay == null) {
        FromObservable.ObserveOn(RxApp.DeferredScheduler).Subscribe(ret.Add);
        return ret;
    }

    // On a timer, dequeue items from queue if they are available
    var queue = new Queue<T>();
    var disconnect = Observable.Timer(WithDelay.Value, WithDelay.Value)
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.DeferredScheduler).Subscribe(_ => {
            if (queue.Count > 0) { 
                ret.Add(queue.Dequeue());
            }
        });

    // When new items come in from the observable, stuff them in the queue.
    // Using the DeferredScheduler guarantees we'll always access the queue
    // from the same thread.
    FromObservable.ObserveOn(RxApp.DeferredScheduler).Subscribe(queue.Enqueue);

    // This is a bit clever - keep a running count of the items actually 
    // added and compare them to the final count of items provided by the
    // Observable. Combine the two values, and when they're equal, 
    // disconnect the timer
    ret.ItemsAdded.Scan0(0, ((acc, _) => acc+1)).Zip(FromObservable.Aggregate(0, (acc,_) => acc+1), 
        (l,r) => (l == r)).Where(x => x != false).Subscribe(_ => disconnect.Dispose());

    return ret;
}
```