# Rx operator to distinct sequences

Tags: c#, system.reactive

**IMPORTANT**: for a description of the results and some more details, please have a look also to my answer

I need to group and filter a sequence of objects/events that usually are replicated, buffering them with a TimeSpan interval. I try to explain it better with sort of marble diagrams:

```
X-X-X-X-X-Y-Y-Y-Z-Z-Z-Z-X-X-Y-Z-Z
```

would produce

```
X---Y---Z---X---Y---Z
```

where X, Y and Z are different event types, and '---' means the interval.
Additionally, I would also like to distinct by a key property that it is available on all types because they have a common base class:

```
X, Y, Z : A
```

and A contains a property Key. Using the notation X.a meaning X.Key = a, A final sample would be:

```
X.a-X.b-X.a-Y.b-Y.c-Z.a-Z.a-Z.c-Z.b-Z.c
```

would produce

```
X.a-X.b---Y.b-Y.c-Z.a-Z.c-Z.b
```

Can anybody help me putting together the required Linq operators (probably DistinctUntilChanged and Buffer) to achieve this behavior?
Thanks

**UPDATE 18.08.12**:

as requested, I try to give a better explanation.
We have devices collecting and sending events to a web service. These devices have an old logic (and we can't change it due to backward compatibility) and they continuously send an event until they receive an acknowledge; after the acknowledge, they send the next event in their queue, and so on.
Events contain the network address of the unit and some other properties distinguishing events in the queue for each device.
An event looks like this:

```
class Event
{
    public string NetworkAddress { get; }

    public string EventCode { get; }

    public string AdditionalAttribute { get; }
}
```

The goal is that of processing every 5 seconds the distinguished events received from all devices, storing information in the database (that's why we don't want to do it in batches) and sending the ack to the device.
Let's make an example with only two devices and some events:

```
Device 'a':
Event 1 (a1): NetworkAddress = '1', EventCode = A, AdditionalAttribute = 'x'
Event 2 (a2): NetworkAddress = '1', EventCode = A, AdditionalAttribute = 'y'
Event 3 (a3): NetworkAddress = '1', EventCode = B, AdditionalAttribute = 'x'

Device 'b':
Event 1 (b1): NetworkAddress = '2', EventCode = A, AdditionalAttribute = 'y'
Event 2 (b2): NetworkAddress = '2', EventCode = B, AdditionalAttribute = 'x'
Event 3 (b3): NetworkAddress = '2', EventCode = B, AdditionalAttribute = 'y'
Event 4 (b4): NetworkAddress = '2', EventCode = C, AdditionalAttribute = 'x'

Pn are the operations done by our server, explained later
```

Possible marble diagram (input streams + output stream):

```
Device 'a'          : -[a1]-[a1]-[a1]----------------[a2]-[a2]-[a2]-[a3]-[a3]-[a3]-...
Device 'b'          : ------[b1]-[b1]-[b2]-[b2]-[b2]------[b3]-[b3]-[b4]-[b4]-[b4]-...

Time                : ------------[1s]-----------[2s]------------[3s]------------[4s]-
DB/acks (rx output) : ------------[P1]-----------[P2]------------[P3]------------[P4]-

P1: Server stores and acknowledges [a1] and [b1]
P2: "      "      "   "            [b2]
P3: "      "      "   "            [a2] and [b3]
P4: "      "      "   "            [a3] and [b4]
```

At the end I think it is probably a simple combination of basic operators, but I'm new to Rx and I'm a bit confused since it seems that there are lots of operators (or combinations of operators) to get the same output stream.

**Update 19.08.12**:

Please keep in mind that this code runs on a server and it should run for days without memory leaks...I'm not sure about the behavior of subjects. At the moment, for each event I call a push operation on a service, which calls the OnNext of a Subject on top of which I should build the query (if I'm not wrong about the usage of subjects).

**Update 20.08.12**:

Current implementation, including validation test; this is what I tried and it seems the same suggested by @yamen

```
public interface IEventService
{
    // Persists the events
    void Add(IEnumerable<Event> events);
}

public class Event
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Implements the logic to handle events.
/// </summary>
public class EventManager : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly TimeSpan EventHandlingPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    private readonly Subject<EventMessage> subject = new Subject<EventMessage>();

    private readonly IDisposable subscription;

    private readonly object locker = new object();

    private readonly IEventService eventService;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EventManager"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="scheduler">The scheduler.</param>
    public EventManager(IEventService eventService, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        this.eventService = eventService;
        this.subscription = this.CreateQuery(scheduler);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pushes the event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="eventMessage">The event message.</param>
    public void PushEvent(EventMessage eventMessage)
    {
        Contract.Requires(eventMessage != null);
        this.subject.OnNext(eventMessage);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // Dispose unmanaged resources
        }

        this.subject.Dispose();
        this.subscription.Dispose();
    }

    private IDisposable CreateQuery(IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        var buffered = this.subject
            .DistinctUntilChanged(new EventComparer())
            .Buffer(EventHandlingPeriod, scheduler);

        var query = buffered
            .Subscribe(this.HandleEvents);
        return query;
    }

    private void HandleEvents(IList<EventMessage> eventMessages)
    {
        Contract.Requires(eventMessages != null);
        var events = eventMessages.Select(this.SelectEvent);
        this.eventService.Add(events);
    }

    private Event SelectEvent(EventMessage message)
    {
        return new Event { Description = "evaluated description" };
    }

    private class EventComparer : IEqualityComparer<EventMessage>
    {
        public bool Equals(EventMessage x, EventMessage y)
        {
            return x.NetworkAddress == y.NetworkAddress && x.EventCode == y.EventCode && x.Attribute == y.Attribute;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(EventMessage obj)
        {
            var s = string.Concat(obj.NetworkAddress + "_" + obj.EventCode + "_" + obj.Attribute);
            return s.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}

public class EventMessage
{
    public string NetworkAddress { get; set; }

    public byte EventCode { get; set; }

    public byte Attribute { get; set; }

    // Other properties
}
```

And the test:

```
public void PushEventTest()
    {
        const string Address1 = "A:2.1.1";
        const string Address2 = "A:2.1.2";

        var eventServiceMock = new Mock<IEventService>();

        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
        var target = new EventManager(eventServiceMock.Object, scheduler);
        var eventMessageA1 = new EventMessage { NetworkAddress = Address1, EventCode = 1, Attribute = 4 };
        var eventMessageB1 = new EventMessage { NetworkAddress = Address2, EventCode = 1, Attribute = 5 };
        var eventMessageA2 = new EventMessage { NetworkAddress = Address1, EventCode = 1, Attribute = 4 };
        scheduler.Schedule(() => target.PushEvent(eventMessageA1));
        scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () => target.PushEvent(eventMessageB1));
        scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), () => target.PushEvent(eventMessageA1));

        scheduler.AdvanceTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6).Ticks);

        eventServiceMock.Verify(s => s.Add(It.Is<List<Event>>(list => list.Count == 2)), Times.Once());

        scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () => target.PushEvent(eventMessageB1));

        scheduler.AdvanceTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(11).Ticks);

        eventServiceMock.Verify(s => s.Add(It.Is<List<Event>>(list => list.Count == 1)), Times.Once());
    }
```

Additionally, I remark again that it is really important that the software could run for days without problems, handling thousands of messages.
To make it clear: the test doesn't pass with the current implementation.

Comment: The final sequence in your question `X.a-X.b---Y.b-Y.c-Z.a-Z.c-Z.b` only shows one `---` interval. Is that right or should the interval be between each value?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the marble diagrams as a source and target 'to scale' below each other, or provided a 'real' example for us to help you with.

Comment: Thanks for the catch Enigmativity, I will fix the output
@yamen I will add more details

Comment: Could you please post an example to indicate how the desired behavior is different from that given by DistinctUntilChanged with a key selector function? Specifically, you mention a TimeSpan - how is that used?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this does exactly what you'd like, but you may be to group the elements explicitly using the `group` keyword, and then to manipulate the various `IObservable`s separately before recombining them.

E.g. if we have class definitions such as

```
class A
{
    public char Key { get; set; }
}

class X : A { }
...
```

and a `Subject<A>`

```
Subject<A> subject = new Subject<A>();
```

then we can write

```
var buffered =
    from a in subject
    group a by new { Type = a.GetType(), Key = a.Key } into g
    from buffer in g.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300))
    where buffer.Any()
    select new
    {
        Count = buffer.Count,
        Type = buffer.First().GetType().Name,
        Key = buffer.First().Key
    };

buffered.Do(Console.WriteLine).Subscribe();
```

We can test this with the data you provided:

```
subject.OnNext(new X { Key = 'a' }); 
Thread.Sleep(100);
subject.OnNext(new X { Key = 'b' }); 
Thread.Sleep(100);
subject.OnNext(new X { Key = 'a' }); 
Thread.Sleep(100);
...
subject.OnCompleted();
```

To get the output you provided:

```
{ Count = 2, Type = X, Key = a }
{ Count = 1, Type = X, Key = b }
{ Count = 1, Type = Y, Key = b }
{ Count = 1, Type = Y, Key = c }
{ Count = 2, Type = Z, Key = a }
{ Count = 2, Type = Z, Key = c }
{ Count = 1, Type = Z, Key = b }
```

Comment: Even if not 100% precise, I assign here the bounty because at the time of the answer the question was not clear enough.
Anyway, the answer is quite well argued.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but it seems to support your use cases.

First, let's define the base class to use (you can easily modify this to suit your needs):

```
public class MyEvent
{
    public string NetworkAddress { set; get; }
    public string EventCode { set; get; }
}
```

Let's set up your devices as an array of `IObservable<MyEvent>` - you may have these available differently, and the below would need to change to accommodate that of course. These devices will each produce a value with a random delay between 0.5 and 1.5 seconds.

```
var deviceA = new MyEvent[] { new MyEvent() {NetworkAddress = "A", EventCode = "1"},
                              new MyEvent() {NetworkAddress = "A", EventCode = "1"},
                              new MyEvent() {NetworkAddress = "A", EventCode = "2"} };

var deviceB = new MyEvent[] { new MyEvent() {NetworkAddress = "B", EventCode = "1"},
                              new MyEvent() {NetworkAddress = "B", EventCode = "2"},
                              new MyEvent() {NetworkAddress = "B", EventCode = "2"},
                              new MyEvent() {NetworkAddress = "B", EventCode = "3"} };   

var random = new Random();                                 

var deviceARand = deviceA.ToObservable().Select(a => Observable.Return(a).Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(random.Next(500,1500)))).Concat();
var deviceBRand = deviceB.ToObservable().Select(b => Observable.Return(b).Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(random.Next(500,1500)))).Concat();

var devices = new IObservable<MyEvent>[] { deviceARand, deviceBRand };
```

Now let's take all of these individual device streams, make them 'distinct', and merge them into a single master stream:

```
var stream = devices.Aggregate(Observable.Empty<MyEvent>(), (acc, device) => acc.DistinctUntilChanged(a => a.EventCode).Merge(device));
```

Once you have that, getting this stream to be consumed periodically is just a matter of buffering it with `Buffer`:

```
stream.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Subscribe(x => { /* code here works on a list of the filtered events per second */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

After searches and experiments, I put together some code that produces the output that I expect:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string Address1 = "A:2.1.1";
        const string Address2 = "A:2.1.2";
        var comparer = new EventComparer();
        var eventMessageA1 = new EventMessage { NetworkAddress = Address1, EventCode = 1, Attribute = 4 };
        var eventMessageB1 = new EventMessage { NetworkAddress = Address2, EventCode = 1, Attribute = 5 };
        var eventMessageA2 = new EventMessage { NetworkAddress = Address1, EventCode = 1, Attribute = 5 };
        var list = new[] { eventMessageA1, eventMessageA1, eventMessageB1, eventMessageA2, eventMessageA1, eventMessageA1 };

        var queue = new BlockingCollection<EventMessage>();
        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Subscribe
            (
                l => list.ToList().ForEach(m =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Producing {0} on thread {1}", m, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    queue.Add(m);
                })
            );

        // subscribing
        queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()
            .ToObservable()
             .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
             .Subscribe(e =>
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("Queue contains {0} items", queue.Count);
                     e.Distinct(comparer).ToList().ForEach(m =>
                  Console.WriteLine("{0} - Consuming: {1} (queue contains {2} items)", DateTime.UtcNow, m, queue.Count));
                 }
             );

        Console.WriteLine("Type enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class EventComparer : IEqualityComparer<EventMessage>
    {
        public bool Equals(EventMessage x, EventMessage y)
        {
            var result = x.NetworkAddress == y.NetworkAddress && x.EventCode == y.EventCode && x.Attribute == y.Attribute;
            return result;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(EventMessage obj)
        {
            var s = string.Concat(obj.NetworkAddress + "_" + obj.EventCode + "_" + obj.Attribute);
            return s.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public class EventMessage
    {
        public string NetworkAddress { get; set; }

        public byte EventCode { get; set; }

        public byte Attribute { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            const string Format = "{0} ({1}, {2})";
            var s = string.Format(Format, this.NetworkAddress, this.EventCode, this.Attribute);
            return s;
        }
    }
```

Anyway, monitoring the application, it seems that this causes a memory leak.
My question is now:

- what is causing the memory leak? [please see the update below]
- is this the best way to do it (if I put the distinct on the first observable, I don't get the other events on next buffers, but items in each buffer should be isolated from others)?
- how can I write a test using the test scheduler?

**UPDATE**:

it seems that the memory increment lasts only some minutes, then the value is stable. I will run a long test.
Of course, this would be an absolutely acceptable behavior.

**UPDATE 26.08.12**:

- as I already mentioned in the previous update, the memory usage increases only (and slowly) for some minutes after the startup. After 8 hours the memory consumed was stable, with normal fluctuations in the range of few KB)
- this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505529/rx-iobservable-buffering-to-smooth-out-bursts-of-events) is very similar to mine and the suggested Drain extension could apply well to my problem (still to be verified)

Anyway, I think that my question is still open for **unit tests using the test scheduler**.

thanks
Francesco