# How to use Interval as a timer to check a webAPI service and return an observable sequence of new values

Tags: c#, system.reactive

So, in my mind this is pretty simple. I want to use Interval as a timer to check a WebAPI service every second and then use Distinct to filter it such that I only get notifications when a new value is added.

(ed. I suppose it's good form to highlight early on that I'm using Reactive Extensions for .Net and that's where these terms come from, `Interval(...)` and `Distinct()`).

When it comes to implementation I have an async function that returns a `Task<PostalCodeModel[]>` where the `PostalCodeModel` is pretty simple dummy model:

```
public class PostalCodeModel
{
    public int PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public PostalCodeModel(int code, string name)
    {
        this.PostalCode = code;
        this.City = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} = {1}", PostalCode, City);
    }
}
```

In my test app I have so far been able to figure out how to create the Interval timer:

```
var interval = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

and using the `ToObservable()` on the Async method:

```
///Bad!
private static IObservable<PostalCodeModel[]> CheckPostalCodes()
{
    using (ApiClient client = new ApiClient("http://localhost:55457"))
    {
        return client.GetPostalCodesAsync().ToObservable();
    }
}

//Good, thanks Enigmativity!
private static IObservable<PostalCodeModel[]> CheckPostalCodes()
{
    return Observable.Using(
        () => new ApiClient("http://localhost:55457"),
        client => client.GetPostalCodesAsync().ToObservable())
        .Take(1);
}
```

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to chain these together and where to apply the Distinct method, my attempts so far have been unsucessful:

```
// No workie :(
var sup = interval.Subscribe(
            CheckPostalCodes,
            () => Console.WriteLine("Completed"));
```

Ideally I would do something like:

```
// No workie :(
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).CheckPostalCodes().Distinct()
```

or similar, but I can't figure out how to do that. Or even if that's a good idea. Eventually the output of this needs to dictate changes in the GUI. And I'm not even sure if using Distinct on an Array of objects works the way I expect it to (only let me know if there is a new value in the array).

---

As I noted in the comment to `Enigmativity`s answer below, after correcting the `CheckPostalCodes()` like he suggested, the subscription was pretty simple, however I did need to add a keySelector to the Distinct call, for it to be able to correctly determine if the returned array is the same. I think simply using `array.Count()` is sufficient for our purposes, i.e.:

```
        var query = Observable
                        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                        .SelectMany(_ => CheckPostalCodes())
                        .Distinct(array => array.Count());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written the `CheckPostalCodes` method incorrectly. The `using` statement has well and truly finished before any observable will have subscribed. You need to use the `Observable.Using` method instead.

Also, if you are only expecting one value back from your API call don't forget to add a `.Take(1)` to make sure the observable stops after one return value.

So `CheckPostalCodes` should look like this:

```
private static IObservable<PostalCodeModel[]> CheckPostalCodes()
{
    return
        Observable
            .Using(
                () => new ApiClient("http://localhost:55457"),
                client => client.GetPostalCodesAsync().ToObservable())
            .Take(1);
    }
}
```

Now you can easily put it all together:

```
var query =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .SelectMany(n => CheckPostalCodes())
        .Distinct();
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This works to create the sequence, but it is as I feared, Distinct doesn't "deep compare" the array and I get a repeating sequence of the same array value, i.e subscribing with:

```query.Subscribe(array => Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} {string.Join(", ", (object[]) array)}"));``` I get repeats of something like: 
```11.5.2017 13:15:36 110 = Name1, 210 = Name2
11.5.2017 13:15:37 110 = Name1, 210 = Name2```

Comment: I wonder if I need to do a comparer, like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916038/rx-operator-to-distinct-sequences - or does one exist somewhere for arrays?

Comment: Actually, I suppose this will be sufficient, since we control on the other end what / how we add to the array: ```var query = Observable
                            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                            .SelectMany(_ => CheckPostalCodes())
                            .Distinct(array => array.Count());```

Comment: Can you explain why the Take(1) is needed, would there be a memory leak if it was not included?

Comment: Also, what would be the best / correct way to handle errors in the Async call, i.e. if the service times-out or returns anything other than OK (it's a HTTP service after all)?

Comment: @gakera - The line "if you are only expecting one value back from your API call don't forget to add a `.Take(1)` to make sure the observable stops after one return value" explains the `.Take(1))`.

Comment: @gakera - You really need to look for existing answers with regard to the handling of errors. If you can't find an existing question/answer then ask a new question.